# Не отображается JButton, пока не наведёшь мышкой

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

У меня есть класс наследующий `JPanel`, в котором переопределён метод `paint()`. В `paint()` отрисовываются разные изображения, текст. Сейчас мне понадобилось добавить кнопку, и тут вышла проблемка. Проблема собственно в том, что `JButton` не отображается, а точнее, она находится под отрисованными элементами и появляется только после наведения (при чём лишь на несколько миллисекунд).

Код:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

    //отрисовка изображений и текста

    button.setBounds(getWidth()/2-125, getHeight()/2+100, 250, 50);
    add(button);
}
```

Каждые 20 миллисекунд всё перерисовывается (`repaint()`) через таймер. Пробовал добавить в начале метода `paint()` `super.paint(g)` - ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто же добавляет кнопки в методе `paint()` (этот метод старый, нужно использовать `paintComponent()`), если этот метод вызывается контейнером автоматически для рисования компонента? Надо добавлять компоненты на панель при инициализации и до того, как панель будет показана/нарисована. Если вы добавляете компоненты динамически, то необходимо перерисовать панель после добавления.

Comment: Поменял на `paintComponent()` и всё нормально заработало, правда сильно повысилось потребление производительности/оперативки. Попробую вытащить лишнее оттуда в метод для инициализации, большое спасибо