# Отрисовка картинки повернутой в направлении движения | Graphics | Graphics2D

Tags: java, математика, swing, геометрия

Надо отрисовать картинку повернутую в направлении движения (поворот должен быть относительно центра картинки):

Пример: [image]

Я знаю скорость по x и y, и положение картинки(x,y), и размер картинки(ширина и высота), а так же размер поля на котором рисую

---

Я пробовал так:

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
g.rotate(Math.toRadians(Math.atan(vx/vy))); // vx,vy - скорость по x и y
g.fillRect((int)(x-w/2), (int) (y-h/2), w, h); // Это я потом заменю на картинку
```

но картинка повернута НЕ относительно центра и поворот неправильный

---

Подробности:

1. Рисую на JPanel в методе `paint(Graphics gr)`
2. Использую Graphics2D

Comment: Панель это легковесное окно, и используется другой метод отрисовки. Чтобы не было проблем с отрисовкой см. [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/872912/204920).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Math.atan` требует отношения `y/x`, но это не так важно, потому что см. ниже
2. `Math.atan` нужно заменить на `Math.atan2(vy, vx)`, чтобы получить угол во всём диапазоне
3. Результат `Math.atan/atan2` уже в радианах, не нужно ещё преобразовывать, если `rotate` требует радианов

Для поворота относительно определенной точки `(cx, cy)` матрица аффинного преобразования строится так:

```
перенос на (-cx, -cy)
поворот
перенос на (cx, cy)
```

В Graphics2D я вижу для этого перекрытый метод:

```
rotate(double theta,  double x,  double y)
```

Comment: картинка рисуется где-то в стороне (центр смещен)

Comment: ....добавил ....

Comment: все равно, что то не получается (cx и cy -  это у меня центр JPanel)

Comment: Что именно не так?

Comment: картинка рисуется где-то в стороне

Comment: Это достаточно абстрактно. Отслеживайте, где ошибки. Например, что такое x и y в `(int)(x-w/2), (int) (y-h/2),` - центр, не левый верхний угол?

Comment: если убрать поворот, то `fillRect` рисует верно

Comment: Поверните на Pi/4 и посмотрите, куда смещается, и что надо изменить.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, я вот что сделал:
`int posX = (int) x + w + cx;`
`int posY = (int) y + h + cy;`
`g.rotate(-Math.atan2(px, py), posX, posY);`
`g.fillRect(posX, posY, w, h);`
`g.rotate(Math.atan2(px, py), posX, posY);`